# Static modifier requirement in class/page

Tags: c#, asp.net

**EDIT** : Sorry. It seems I got a little confused. I was attempting to call a non-static method within a static method, and it wasn't working. They were in the same class. That led me to (incorrectly) assume that I cannot call a non-static without instantiation, even though they belong to the same class.
Since I already created the question, allow me to change the question a little. Why can I not call a non-static method within a static one? Here's my code so that you can tell me if I'm just screwing myself over with something silly:

```
public class DataAccessObjectClass
{
    public static IList<Records> GetAllRecords(Dictionary<string,string> searchDic)
    {
        string query = BuildSearchQuery(searchDic); //error: object ref. required
    }

    public string BuildSearchQuery(Dictionary<string,string> searchDic)
    {
        string query = "";
        //build the query
        return string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `GetAllObjects()` defined, in this example?

Comment: @TiesonT. Within the same class.

Comment: `Page_Load` isn't `static`. You're already running *inside* a non-static method when you call `GetObjects`. Nothing special to that call.

Comment: @JWLim I see `GetObjects()`, which is not the same thing. Is that a typo?

Comment: @TiesonT. Oops. Yep, typo. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate the class because it's already been instantiated for you.

Consider the class

```
public class C
{
    public void f() { g(); }
    public void g() { }
}
```

Now, you cannot simply call `C.g();`, you need an instance to call it on. `new C().g();` would work, but so would

```
var c = new C();
c.g();
```

The call from `f` to `g` already has an instance to call `g` on, which is `this`. There, `g();` simply means `this.g();`. `c.f();` would end up calling `c.g()` from within `f`.

For your edited question, consider this class:

```
public class D
{
    public static void f() { g(); } // error
    public void g() { }
}
```

Now, because `D.f` is `static`, you could call it as simply `D.f();`. In that case, there isn't any instance of `D` at all yet, so you have no instance to call `g` on. (Or, if you do create instances of `D` first, the system wouldn't know which of those instances to call `g` on.)

Comment: Hold on. Am I supposed to be able to call `g` in `f` like in your example? Is that supposed to work? Or did you mean that I still need to instantiate `C` before calling `g`?

Comment: @JWLim The whole point is that you *can* call `g` like that from `f`. `C` has already been instantiated. How would you call `f` if it hadn't been?

Comment: Facepalm. Sorry. Please see my edit in the question.

Comment: @JWLim Does my edit help, or does it just end up more confusing?

Comment: Well, I can't say I understand. How can there be no instance of `D`? And besides, I thought the static modifier meant that there would always only be one instance of that method?

Comment: Btw I've included the actual code in my edit. If that would help.

Comment: @JWLim There's no instance of `D` if you've never done `new D()` anywhere. A class can have instances, not a method. What `static` means is that the method does not need any class instances to be called, whereas a non-static method does.

Comment: @JWLim For your edited question, you can probably just make `BuildSearchQuery` static too, if that one is also intended to be useful without any `new DataAccessObjectClass()`.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. I was thinking of avoiding the use of the `static` modifier for the `BuildSearchQuery` method, and also declaring it `protected`, since it would only be used at rare situations and would be called by internal methods. I read somewhere that declaring everything `static` isn't exactly ideal. So I suppose I'll probably instantiate the class from within the `GetAllRecords` method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JWLim Note that you can combine `static` and `protected` (or even `private`), `static` doesn't need to be `public`. You're of course free to do whatever you want, but IMO it doesn't make sense to instantiate the class within `GetAllRecords`, if you're not going to do anything with that instance. There's no need to avoid `static` in that case. Or, if you do want an instance for whatever reason, make both methods instance methods (remove `static` from both), and let the caller worry about doing `new DataAccessObjectClass()`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it something in the System.Web.UI.Page class?

No, It is because you're already inside the instance method. There is an implicit instance `this` which already exist in the context, `this` instance will be used to call that method.

There is nothing special with `Page` class, in any class you can do the same, You can call whatever instance method from another instance method without an instance(although you're technically using this as implicit reference).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Page_Load` is beeing called when the page is rendered, so, there is an instantiate of the class `DefaultPage`, and this object is the one that is calling to `Page_Load` and to `GetObjects`.